# How does the SOLID principle apply to method overrides in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, oop, solid-principles

I read an explanation of the "[SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))" principle. Here is an explanation of the 'L' part:

> objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their
>   subtypes without altering the correctness of that program

So for example I have `MYViewController : UIViewController`

when I override `viewDidLoad`, it means that I changed the base view controller's logic. Right? Does it mean that I am **altering the correctness of that program**?

Or did I misunderstand that point?

Comment: It's still an instance of a UIViewController w/all the required/inherited properties & methods. It would be "incorrect" if you override `-viewDidLoad` to not call `super` or otherwise break/ignore what the superclass is supposed to do in that method. Adding things & making it more specialized seems to still meet the intent ... but that's just my opinion.

Comment: does it mean that I need to call [super viewDidLoad] every time? or if I have `- testMethod` in base class and in subclass I want to overwrite it then I every time should invoke `[super testMethod]` in subclass `- testMethod`?

Comment: For example I have class `Shape` and method `- whatIsShape` in some case I have shape which is `Square` and in other case I have shape which is `Circle` and depend on needs I overwrite `- whatIsShape` to return string "It's a square or it's a "it's a circle". And the base class return string "It's just a shape" (or print string). In this case I want to print base class string and subclass string I need to call `[super whatIsShape]` in `- whatIsShape` subclass method, but actually I can skip it. So and my question "am I altering the correctness of that program?" if I skip base class invocation?

Comment: In Objective-C, method swizzling is how you violate the 'L'. Normal method overrides are fine, unless -- as mentioned above -- you fail to call up to super.

Comment: @Rob thanks Rob, I've added one more comment above your)

Comment: @Rob oh ok got it, for example if viewDidLoad will be a subclass method that will return ice creams objects (just for example it return void I know=)) than we totally affect on logic right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you override `viewDidLoad` does not constitute a violation of Liskov substitution principle (LSP). (The function of a subclass generally is to expand upon the behavior of the superclass.) It's actually the other way around, that you violate this LSP if you implement behavior in the subclass such that it could no longer be used in cases where you reference the base class.

But LSP isn't a situation where we're contemplating a completely different class (e.g. ice cream object; lol). We're generally concerned where we're dealing with an actual subclass, but one that can no longer replace a reference to its base class.

When overriding a method, if the the code calls the `super` implementation as appropriate, it generally satisfies LSP. And to your question about `viewDidLoad`, you always want to call `super` in that case.

Comment: yea viewDidLoad is was just an example, I every time call `super` but just wanted to clarify "altering the correctness of that program" because we seems every time overwrite some logic depend on needs.

Comment: one more question what if we say about custom method, should we call super every time then, if we not say about `- viewDidLoad`

Comment: When you override a method, you generally want to call `super`. If your method is not overriding a superclass method, then, obviously, don't. As an aside, don't make _too_ much about calling `super` re LSP: It's actually neither necessary nor sufficient. It's just a common example.  And this might be heretical, but don't go too crazy about LSP, either. You may elect to violate LSP (a view controller technically violates LSP when it introduces new preconditions, which is not uncommon). LSP is an excellent design principle when designing class hierarchy, but not one to be followed blindly.